# Outputting a video feed (OpenCV + picamera) to GUI using Tkinter or guizero in Raspberry PI?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm following this tutorial
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/04/21/python-opencv-show-video-tkinter-window/
and found out that it is only for a usb camera.

I have this code for using picamera on my OpenCV scripts.

```
class VideoStream:
    def __init__(self, resolution=(640,480),framerate=30):
        from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
        from picamera import PiCamera
        self.camera = PiCamera()
        self.camera.resolution = resolution
        self.camera.framerate = framerate
        self.rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera,size=resolution)
        self.stream = self.camera.capture_continuous(
            self.rawCapture, format = "bgr", use_video_port = True)

        self.frame = []
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.update,args=()).start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        for f in self.stream:
            self.frame = f.array
            self.rawCapture.truncate(0)
            if self.stopped:
                self.stream.close()
                self.rawCapture.close()
                self.camera.close()

    def read(self):
         return self.frame

    def stop(self):
         self.stopped = True
```

This works if i'm using the GUI of OpenCV (cv2.imshow) but I want to have the output on a different GUI because I would like to add some texts and buttons to it.